# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a)

Tags: php, mysql

```html
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
$pass = password_hash($contraseña,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$consu = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' ";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consu);


if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){

header("location: intentar.html");

}else{
    
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (email, contraseña) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $pass . "')") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
                 
  header("location: registro.html");
  
}


}


?>
```

Este es mi codigo

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO registros (email,contraseña) VALUES ('$email', '$pass')") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Esta bien escrito, pero no envia los datos a la base de datos.

Uso Xampp de 32bits y mysql.

Algo raro es que si envio datos a la base de datos en otra hoja php, si se envian pero en esta hoja no...

Comment: Agrega mas info, por favor, porque es muy ambigua la pregunta... Es decir, mysql te esta diciendo que hay un caracter no valido cerca del error o en su defecto en la linea de la query. Sin embargo solo adjuntas la query sin mas contexto

Comment: capaz, capaz.. que le molesta que tu campo se llame contraseña...

Comment: Edgar Gc si amigo, pero como digo no creo que sea un error en el codigo (para mi), que puede ser de xampp, por que el codigo funciona en otras computadoras de 64bits y en esta no... digo

Comment: gbianchi, no funciona con eso...

Comment: Trata siempre de evitar el uso de `ñ`, acentos y caracteres especiales cuando declaras variables, nombres de tabla, columnas, etc. Luego, asegura bien la codificación (poniendo utf-8 en todos los contextos). El error aquí se debe sin ninguna duda a un problema de codificación, y por el mensaje parece estar en el contenido de una de tus variables. Para depurarlo, haz un `var_dump($email);` y un `var_dump($pass);` y revisa, pues se está colando un carácter extraño en el contenido. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) sobre el problema de la codificación.