# Php no envia datos a base de datos mysqli cuando creo mas de una columna

Tags: php, mysqli

Cuando envio datos a la BDD mysql con dos columnas, este no carga los dos. Si subo con una sola columna si muestra en la base de datos.

Ej:

Funciona cuando inserto datos en una columna (ejemplo sin columna contraseña).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando agrego datos con contraseña, osea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no me muestra los datos (filas) de tanto como email y contraseña.

codigo de insertar:

```html
  <form method="POST">

  <input type="email" id="name" required name="email"  placeholder="Email"/>
  <input type="text" name="texto">
  
  <input type="submit"  name="submit"/>

</div>
</form>

<?php

include ("conexion.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email = $_POST['email'];
$texto = $_POST['texto'];

mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (email,contraseña) VALUES ('$email','$texto')");


}else{
   echo "no insertado";
}
  
?>
```

Comment: No te muestra los datos en donde? ese query parece estar bien... tira algun error?

Comment: Aunque, en teoría, MySQL soporta caracteres especiales o con tilde en nombres de columna, es recomendable evitarlos. O bien, puedes encerrar los nombres de columna entre acentos graves `\``, por ejemplo: `INSERT INTO usuarios (\`email\`, \`contraseña\`) ...`. Además, te recomiendo usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para reducir riesgo de errores y ataques SQL.

Comment: el error es que me dice que se envio, pero... no muestra los datos en la base de datos

Comment: ¿No es [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/447323/16597) el mismo problema?

Comment: no marcos, el problema es que mysqli no agrega datos enviados por php a la BDD, cuando hay mas de una columna

Comment: solo quiero saber como agregar datos si tengo mas de una columna...

Comment: Si despues de la linea de mysqli_query haces print_r(mysqli_error($conexion)) que te sale en pantalla?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que cambies el nombre de tu columna "contraseña" a una palabra sin la "ñ" porque te puede estar ocasionando conflicto para reconocer el nombre.

Comment: GRACIAAAAASSSSSS AMIGOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!, FUE EXTRAÑO QUE YO HICE LO QUE ME PEDISTE ANTES Y NO FUNCIONABA.... PERO GRACIASSS!!!